# How can I change isLogin before mounting?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

```
import Router from 'next/router';


class App extends NextApp {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLogin: false
    }
  }

 componentDidMount() {
    if (JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("APIKEY"))) {
      return
    }

    if (!this.state.isLogin) {
      Router.push('/login')
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The official suggestion is to use the `constructor`.
(see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)